# Как использовать SQLite в Unity WebGL? (Ошибка "UnityLoader.js:1144 To use dlopen, you need to use Emscripten's linking support")

Tags: unity3d, sqlite, sqlite3, webgl, emscripten

Я успешно использую SQLite3 в Unity3D для платформ Android, Windows и в редакторе Unity.

После компиляции под WebGL, при запуске в консоли браузера возникает ошибка:

```
UnityLoader.js:1144 To use dlopen, you need to use Emscripten's linking support, see https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Linking
printErr @ UnityLoader.js:1144
onAbort @ UnityLoader.js:1134
abort @ e34a563e-2a8d-4c34-a8f9-f5c9b496b4fe:25837
_dlopen @ e34a563e-2a8d-4c34-a8f9-f5c9b496b4fe:9072
__ZN6il2cpp2osL19LoadLibraryWithNameEPKci @ wasm-04c4b376-50543:4
__ZN6il2cpp2os13LibraryLoader18LoadDynamicLibraryERKNS_5utils10StringViewIcEEi @ wasm-04c4b376-50542:83
__ZN6il2cpp2os13LibraryLoader18LoadDynamicLibraryERKNS_5utils10StringViewIcEE @ wasm-04c4b376-50541:4
__ZN6il2cpp2vm13LibraryLoader18LoadDynamicLibraryENS_5utils10StringViewIcEE @ wasm-04c4b376-51459:5
__ZN6il2cpp2vm14PlatformInvoke7ResolveERK16PInvokeArguments @ wasm-04c4b376-51649:95
__Z22il2cpp_codegen_resolveRK16PInvokeArguments @ wasm-04c4b376-52813:3
__Z30il2cpp_codegen_resolve_pinvokeIPFxlELm8ELm26EET_RAT0__KcRAT1__S3_20Il2CppCallConvention13Il2CppCharSetib @ wasm-04c4b376-24557:39
_SQLite3_LibVersionNumber_mBFD9577E236A35E7EB3D6841A6B9DF3D359276C1 @ wasm-04c4b376-24579:17
_SQLiteConnection__ctor_mF743CE52CDC85FCB3E0C22F7D31F69C701CA87DF @ wasm-04c4b376-24596:102
_SQLiteConnection__ctor_m8A676B0DF4447201678615FABB48B2D36405AE8D @ wasm-04c4b376-24821:30
...
```

из текста которой я заключаю, что проблема при загрузке кода SQLite.

Что я уже пробовал сделать:
Добавил в папку Assets/Plugins/SQLite/WebGL файлы sqlite3.c, sqlite3.h, взяв их из амальгама-сборки. Но это не помогло.

Каким образом можно исправить ошибку?

Comment: Вы полагаете что `mysql` запустится в браузере? боюсь что это слишком круто, чтобы быть правдой,хотя все может быть, но лично я сильно сомневаюсь

Comment: mySql тут ни при чем, речь идет об SQLite

Comment: а как вы используете sqlite, что вы там хранить будете?

Comment: Что там будет храниться - неважно, но если интересно, то географическое местоположение путей железной дороги

Comment: ну в общем веб приложения не имеют доступа к диску, вероятно есть какие-то варианты замкнуть это на `idexeddb` или `websql`, но в целом Ваше приложение должно либо отправлять запросы на сервер либо содержать данные внутри ресурсов.

Comment: Тем не менее, в Unity Assets предлагают платное решение: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/libsqlite-66906, но я не знаю, будет ли оно работать, а для проверки надо купить его.
 Также как вариант нагуглил исходный код SQLite: https://github.com/CsharpDatabase/CsharpSQLite, но боюсь, проверка займет много времени.

Comment: Насчет отсутствия доступа к диску не понятно до конца, т.к. ошибка в приложении возникает после успешно выполненных вызовов File.WriteAllBytes и File.AppendAllText, которые ошибок не выдают.

Comment: wasm и emscripte nиспользуют эмуляцию файловой системы в памяти вкладки браузера и могут работать с ней. это все живет пока живет вкладка, потом это должно быть куда-то записано

Comment: https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html это работает поверх Indexeddb, как я и предполагал выше

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конце концов, я купил в Unity Assets компонент LibSQLite: http://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/libsqlite-66906

Предварительно списался с разработчиками. С налогами получилось 12$. Сейчас компиляция проходит успешно, изменения в БД сохраняются (кешируются между сессиями, даже при перезапуске браузера), если не открывать приложение в приватных вкладках. Кеш находится не в localStorage, как уверяли разработчики, а в IndexedDB. Работает это в браузере Chrome, в IE не работает - не знаю, из-за какого компонента, может быть, из-за другого. На других браузерах не запускал.

Библиотека, оказывается, базируется на sqlite-net, который я и использовал до этого. Мигрировать поэтому было очень просто. Но насчет быстродействия, мне показалось, стало работать медленнее. Бенчмарки не проводил.

Comment: а пробывал с мобилками запускать? люди вроде бы жалуются

Comment: а на что жалуются? я использую на Android уже на втором проекте без проблем, на iOS не пробовал.